# Read error while booting

Tags: 10.10, boot

I am getting the error message `read error` while booting. After power up, I get a black screen with cursor at top, and after a while around 1:30 min. I get a `read error` message at the top.

I shut down and restarted a couple of times, and it went back to normal. Was it a hard-disk error, or was it coming from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean `I/O read error` when reading from the harddisk then it probably is a hardware error. I would check the health of the drive (use **smartmontools** or [Palimpsest Disk Utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palimpsest_Disk_Utility)).

Answer (score 4):

The best way to check your hard disk for errors, is to download diagnose software from the hard disk vendor.

You can also install the program `smartmontools` and

1. Check the S.M.A.R.T. values of the disk using `sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda` (change */dev/sda* to fit your hard disk),
2. Run a self test: `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda` (will take some time, you can check the status of the self test running `sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda`).

Comment: does my error mean I have a hardware error?