# How to retrieve data from a corrupted volume

Tags: 10.10, data-recovery

My Ubuntu 10.10 just crashed, probably due to [hardware error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28394/read-error-while-booting) (and in the end I was getting errors like `Unknown filesystem` ..... `grub> ..`, and it went to the GRUB console before I could take any other action).

I reinstalled the same version from a USB stick. I had Ubuntu installed with the `ext4` file system and I also have the same filesystem in the same hard disk on a different drive.

When I try to access my previous filesystem, I get errors:

```
Error mounting: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda6,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

I had some important files in the previous volume ;  I don't know how to retrieve them.

And what are the chances that I would get the same outcome (hardware error)?
Please help me!

Comment: Well, hopefully you have backups.

Comment: @Olli no i don't have backups :( !

Comment: What does `dmesg | tail -20` say after you have unsuccessfully tried to mount the partition?

Comment: @arrange i am a ubuntu layman !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ddrescue` to make an image of your failing drive/partition. Then use `foremost` on the image you made to try and save files.

As you say you're a layman, that would mean running, these commands:

```
ddrescue -i0 -s50M /dev/sda6 image.dd logfile
ddrescue /dev/sda6 image.dd logfile
ddrescue -d -r3 /dev/sda6 hdimage.dd logfile
```

Good information on how to use ddrescue on [its documentation page](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html).

After that, try foremost on the image:

```
foremost -i image.dd -t all -o savedfiles -v
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a hard drive failure SpinRite (www.grc.com) may be your only hope for disk recovery.